# Exception problem when rebinding DataViewGrid

Tags: c#

I have a List<> that I bind to a DataViewGrid using a Binding source. Like this:

```
    private void BindGridView(DataGridView dgv, List<KeyTextPair> list, Func<KeyTextPair, int, bool> predicate)
   {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = list.Where(predicate);
        dgv.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

I have a collection of such lists, which the user can chose from to display in the DVG. However, upon attempting to change one list for another by rebinding I get the error:

"Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function."

I've looked around for a couple of hours but i still haven't figured out why this is happening.

I'll be very happy if one of you guys can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the `DataSource` to `null`. May or may not help.

Answer (score 0):

In second line you need to convert collection to list:

```
bs.DataSource = list.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

p.s. If that doesn't solve your problem please post your predicate code

cheers

Comment: hi,

no, that fails also. On this predicate:
private bool ShowAllRows(KeyTextPair ktp, int idx)
  {
   return true;
  }